# How do I record and display the output of an EXE Window into another EXE Window

Tags: lua

So for example let's say I have a game running, I want to grab the image output of the game and display it onto another window I have, so I would have two identical looking windows, one with the game itself, and one with the output of it. I want this to be done with LUA.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [wxwidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) library (with [wxlua](https://github.com/pkulchenko/wxlua) wrapper), as it provides access to the screen device context to read its pixels. See for example this [takeScreenshot](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/screenshot.lua#L42) function that saves a section of the display into a PNG file.